# How to replace zero with a small number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, division, zero

I want to replace the divisor with a very small number if it equals to 0. I am doing an operation which is like:

```
A = pow(X,2)/(q - P)
```

It computes these values and stores them in an array (for looped). However, at certain places `q - P = 0`, which throws a runtime error. I know that there is a work around, I do not want that. How can I set q - P to a very small number in case `q - P = 0` for a particular iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use a try except block and set `A` to a different value if a `ZeroDivisionError` error occurs:

```
try:
    A = (pow(X,2))/(q - P))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    A = 99999999999 #big nuber because devision by a small number
                    # you can also set A to infinity with `A = np.inf`
```

If thats not an option for you (e.g. you really want to change q or P and not only A) you can simply add a small number to q or P

```
if q == P:
    q+= 0.00000000000001 # or P+=small_number or q-=small_number or P-=small_number
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inline if:

```
very_small_number = 0.001

A = pow(X, 2) / ( q - P if q != P else very_small_number )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following trick:

```
diff = q - P or .001
A = pow(X, 2) / diff
```

or

```
A = pow(X, 2) / (q - P or .001)
```

Comment: In this example, does the code automatically pass to the 0.001 case if q-P == 0?

Comment: @PyWalker27 In Python `0 == False` so the expression `0 or .001` returns `.001`.